# Compatibility for Thomas & Betts breakers

Tags: electrical-panel

Need to replace Thomas & Betts 2-pole 30 amp breaker for a water heater. What brand would be compatible? Panel is also T&B. TBB10 (20-20) C Model #1

Comment: It may be important _which_ service panel you have. You'll need breakers that are _UL Classified_ for that panel.

Comment: As stated, panel is also Thomas & Betts

Comment: That's a manufacturer, not a panel model. I can't fix "a Chevrolet" without more information either. :)

Comment: Sorry... Panel is T&B  TBB10 (20-20) C model #1

Answer (score 6):

This [handy chart](https://www.platt.com/CutSheets/Eaton%20Distribution/Breakers-ClassifedType.pdf) seems to show that the Eaton CL230 breaker is a "Classified" replacement for the Thomas Betts TB230 breaker.

Since this is a pretty common breaker sold at national [big box home improvement stores](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-CL-30-Amp-2-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-CL230/205308274) it should be straightforward to compare the two.  These cheaper breakers are normally not even in a package, making comparison even easier.

The comment from isherwood about the type of panel you have is valid.  This is meant to point you in the right direction, but its not a definitive "certified" answer.

Comment: The presence of an item on Home Depot's website does not mean they stock it at the stores.  I would not expect them to have Eaton CL in stock. They can certainly order it though.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica True. But the good news with Home Depot (unlike quite a few online+bricks-and-mortar web sites) is that they will (generally) tell you pretty clearly whether it is in your local store (and even exactly where in the store to find it!) or not.

Answer (score 4):

Talk to an Eaton authorized dealer, i.e. an actual *electrical supply house* that deals in Eaton.  They can check their cross reference book to see if the BR busing is compatible (ThreePhaseEel thinks it isn't, which I believe).

If not, they can get the Eaton CL that JPhi1618 mentioned.

Either way, Eaton is your one-shop shop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eaton CL is correct -- if BR was compatible, it'd be a cross-list, not a classification